# UILabel is displaying last value but not all Values which I have given the input

Tags: ios, uilabel

My `UILabel` is not refreshing everytime but refreshing with last value only. I want to print all values in `UILabel`.

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    lblText.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
sleep(1.2);
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here can you be little specific to help you out

Comment: Amit.. I am not sure but according to me iOS redraws the screens between two methods execution. And only latest values are redrawn. To achieve the counter. you need to right a method and start a timer.

Comment: Thanks Kunal,I understand the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want change the labels text interval a certain time , why not use `NSTimer`

```
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(changeText) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    _loopTime = 0;


- (void)changeText
{
    lblText.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",_loopTime++];
    if(_loopTime >= 3)
    {
        [_timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are overriding the values. You need to create a new array appending the new value every iteration.

And also, dont use sleep in the main thread. Thats UI blocking

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `sleep()` in main thread. Because it will freeze UI. Use `performSelector: afterDelay:` which will call function (your own) that will update text in label

Answer (score 1):

Amit.. I am not sure but according to me iOS redraws the screens between two methods execution. And only latest values are redrawn. To achieve the counter. you need to right a method and start a timer as follows.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.2
                                                            target:self
                                                          selector:@selector(counter:)
                                                          userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]
                                                           repeats:YES];
```

This is a counter method.

```
-(void) counter:(NSNumber)count
{

    if(count == 4)
    {
      [timer invalidate]; timer = nil;
    }
    lblText.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count];
    //increment the counter
    i++;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My labels are not updating.